# How can I prove that function is continuous on $E = \left(1,+\infty \right)$

Tags: real-analysis

> I have a function defined as series $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{nx^3}}{x^2+n^2}$ and $E = \left(1,+\infty \right)$. How can I prove that this function is continuous on $E$?

I tried to prove it using uniform convergence but its didn't work because:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\sqrt{nx^3)}}{x^2 + n^2}\right) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = \sqrt{3}n.$$ 
$$\sup_{(1,+\infty)}|f_n(x) - 0| = \lim_{n\to \infty}f_{n}(\sqrt{3}n) = \frac{3^\frac{3}{4}}{4} \not= 0$$

Comment: I think you can show the uniform convergence on $(1,M)$ for some fixed $M > 1$ and then conclude that $f$ is continuous on $(1,M)$. Since $M$ can be chosen arbitrarily, this extends to continuity of $f$ on $E$, even though uniform convergence does not hold on $E$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuity is a local property, therefore it suffices to show the uniform convergence on $(1,R]$ for any $R>1$ and we should consider
$$\sup_{(1,R]}|f_n(x)|.$$
Moreover, note that eventually $R<\sqrt{3}n$ and therefore, according to your work, for such $n$,
$$\sup_{(1,R]}|f_n(x)|=f_n(R)=\frac{\sqrt{nR^3}}{R^2+n^2}< \frac{\sqrt{nR^3}}{n^2}= \frac{R^{3/2}}{n^{3/2}}.$$
Can you take it from here?